# InvalidCastException: Cannot Cast from source type to destination type. sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get data from sqlite table and use it with unity.
This is my code

```
string conn = "URI=file:DB.db"; //Path to database.
    IDbConnection dbconn;
    dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection(conn);
    try
    {
        dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
    string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id =" + LevelID + "";
    dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
    IDataReader reader = null;
    reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader != null)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
           string question = reader.GetString(0);
           string cat = reader.GetString(1);
         }
      }
```

The Exception I get :

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.VerifyType (Int32 i, DbType typ)
Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.GetString (Int32 i)
```

I have checked the database and the field is "TEXT" and the data stored in it is a string and I'm declaring  string , then why it say that it's Int ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `SELECT * FROM mytable` but try being more explicit about what you are selecting. For example, write your query like this instead:

```
SELECT NameOfColumn1, NameOfColumn2, ... FROM mytable
```

It is possible that `Select *` is selecting more columns than just the 2 columns you are expecting (if your table has more columns it will select all of them). Therefore, the casting is breaking.

Comment: Thank you . I was using the second column ( which is Int) instead of the third column ( which is string ) . Changing my code to : `string cat = reader.GetString(2); ` Solved the problem.